# dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell siganture

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, dell

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from 20 to 22 on a Dell Latitude 7430. After rebooted, I get an error as in the image and I cannot move forward.

```
dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell siganture
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0xYI.jpg)

I attached the picture. Is anyone able to give me an hand with this ?

Thanks